# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect HTTP Status 400 - type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a controller to edit details of a user or employee which are already present in my database.

When ever a user clicks edit, data from database is retrieved and the result is displayed in a text field. Next I want to edit those details and save them by clicking 'save'.

I do the following:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url 
 value="/resources/css/table.css"/>">
 </head>
 <body>
 <table border="1" align ="center">
 <thead><tr>
    <th>Sr No</th>
    <th>empid</th>
    <th>emptype</th>
    <th>firstname</th>
    <th>lastname</th>
    <th>phone</th>
    <th>view</th>
    <th>edit</th>
    <th>set permission</th>
        <th>assigned assets</th>
        </tr>
 </thead>
    <c:forEach var="emp" items="${listEmp}" 
 varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
            <td>${emp.empid}</td>
            <td>${emp.emptype}</td>
            <td>${emp.firstname}</td>
            <td>${emp.lastname}</td>
            <td>${emp.phone}</td>
            <td> <a 
href="view/${emp.empid}">view</a></td>
            <td> <a 
href="edit/${emp.empid}">edit</a></td>

</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My backend handles it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}")
public  ModelAndView editdetails(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable("id")long id) {

    List<Editdetails> listshow= userdao.editdetails(id);
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("editdetails");
    mav.addObject("edit",new Editdetails());
    mav.addObject("listshow",listshow);
    return mav;
  }
```

Here is the frontend: editdetails.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" 
uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url 
value="/resources/css/style.css"/>">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO- 
8859-1">
</head>
<title>editform</title>
<body>
<c:forEach var="emp" items="${listshow}" varStatus="status">
<form:form  id="editform1" action="edit12" modelAttribute="edit"  
method="post">
<table align="left">          
<tr>
<td>                        
<form:labelpath="usertype">Usertype</form:label>
</td>
<td>
<form:input path="usertype" name="usertype" id="usertype" 
value="${emp.usertype}" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<form:label path="empid">empid</form:label>
</td>
<td>
<form:input path="empid" name="empid" id="empid" 
value="${emp.empid}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
<form:label path="firstname">FirstName</form:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
<form:input path="firstname" name="firstname" id="firstname"   
value="${emp.firstname}"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<form:label path="lastname">LastName</form:label>
</td>
<td>
<form:input path="lastname" name="lastname" id="lastname"  
value="${emp.lastname}"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<form:label path="email">Email</form:label>
</td>
<td>
<form:input path="email" name="email" id="email" 
value="${emp.email}" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <form:label path="address">Address</form:label>
 </td>
 <td>
 <form:input path="address" name="address" id="address"  
 value="${emp.address}" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <form:label path="phone">Phone</form:label>
 </td>
 <td>
 <form:input path="phone" name="phone" id="phone"  
 value="${emp.phone}" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <form:label path="date">date</form:label>
 </td>
 <td>
 <form:input type="date" path="date" name="date" id="date" 
 value="${emp.date}"/>
 </td>
 </tr>
<tr><td></td>
 <td>
 <input type = "submit" value="save" /> 
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form:form>
 </c:forEach>
 </body>
  </html>
```

I am able to view details, but when I click on save, it shows the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/edit12", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView edituse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute("edit")Editdetails edit) throws InterruptedException {
    ModelAndView mav= new ModelAndView("admin");
            //here i will call some service to save update  
    return mav;
  }
```

Comment: which is the exact stacktrace error?

Comment: `it shows the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect` - can you edit your question and add the whole error message?

Comment: i got it the error was in request mapping i had to map /edit/edit12